# Rule Compilation error : Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Tags: java, mongodb, drools

I am new to mongoDb and drools.
I am writing a rule in drools, which is iterating a java list. But when running tomcat it is giving Rule Compilation error.

Getting List from dao :-

```
List<XYZ> list = new ArrayList<XYZ>();
Query q = query(where("id").is(userId));
list = getMongoOperation().find(q, XYZ.class, "XYZ");
```

Using list in drools engine Rule :-

```
for(XYZ xyzObj : list) 
{           
}
```

Model Class :-

```
@Document(collection="XYZ")
public class XYZ 
{
}
```

I am getting exception when running tomcat. "Rule Compilation error : Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"

Rule File :-

> import java.util.List; import java.util.Iterator; global com.demo.XYZ
>   list
>
> rule '1_Demo_Rule'
>
> when  prop : RULEDEMO( attribute == "demo") then
>
> ```
>   for(XYZ xyzObj : list)          {                   }
> ```

end

Comment: Absolute no experience, but `collection="XYZ"` sounds wrong.

Comment: ... and that's not the Drools rule. Or at least it's not a relevant part of a rule. You haven't shown what `list` is.

Comment: @Steve I have added rule file. please see updated question

Comment: Well, according to that rule, the list is an instance of XYZ, which would explain why you're not able to iterate over it.

Comment: global List<com.demo.XYZ> list, right ?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use the short syntax of the for-statement at all, due to restrictions in the DRL parser.

Given that

```
global List<com.demo.XYZ> list;
```

use the not-so-nice

```
for( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ ){
    XYZ xyzObj = list.get(i);
    // ...
}
```